# Is there any method for opening specific web app by Internet Explorer from MS Edge browser?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I would like to know a method for opening a specific web application in Internet Explorer from within Microsoft Edge, because our web application has some problem with Edge.

Is there any method?

Comment: Incompatible apps should automatically open in IE11 when you attempt to open them in Microsoft Edge. Can you be more specific with regard to "some problem"?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Our clients have been updating to Windows 10 and now they can't seem to use our remote application.

Answer (score 7):

As suggested by TylerH, the first thing to do is determine the precise problem to see if it can be fixed on the site. If it is something that is not expected to work in Edge (e.g. reliance on custom ActiveX control), there are two ways to have the web app prompt to open IE from MS Edge:

1. If it is a public Internet site that you own, email iepo@microsoft.com to have it considered for inclusion on the Compatibility List which determines which sites show the prompt. This is a cloud-hosted list that all Edge browsers download periodically.
2. If you are in a managed PC environment (e.g. enterprise), you can use the [Enterprise Site List](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn640696.aspx) to cause specific intranet, extranet or Internet sites to open in IE for users on those managed PCs.

Comment: We are using Microsoft's Remote App service and it uses ActiveX controls. This does not work in Edge browser nor does it prompt the user to open in IE mode.  Not even the "Enterprise Site List" works in EDGE.  I have followed this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx and this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42501 and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn872481.aspx

Comment: @goroth - Enterprise Site List should work in MS Edge. Try following the guidance here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270205.aspx

Comment: It does not work. Here is a link to what I had to do to get this to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793280/microsoft-edge-browser-ignoring-enterprise-mode-list/31815452#31815452

Comment: @goroth You are correct - there are some issues with the documentation that we will get corrected ASAP. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: How hard would it have been for Edge to implement the technique that IE11 Metro was using in order to let a web page author specify that they want the user to be prompted to open the page in IE11 Desktop? See this article of mine: https://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2015/04/20/howto-open-page-from-internet-explorer-metro-app-into-desktop-ie/