# Accessing local XML files with MS Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, microsoft-edge

A few years back I created a web site that stores all its content in XML files in order to ease translation. The site was specifically designed to be usable locally, ***without any form of server***, and has been distributed to customers as such. There was an issue with Chrome reading the XML files but that was circumvented with a batch file (not an ideal solution) that reset Chrome's allow-file-access-from-files flag on startup. The site works correctly in Internet Explorer 8 and above, but the problem I now have is that it does not load the XML file in MS Edge and I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere on the net, including here.

For reference, I used jQuery to open the XML files. A shortened sample of my code follows:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'common/xml/index.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(xml) {
    function...
  },
  error: function(xml) {
    function...
  }
});
```

The site works perfectly well in Edge when hosted on a server but, as I indicated earlier, this is not how it is distributed and there is no facility to set up a server on each device that it has been copied to. I also can't ask customers to manually change the settings on their browser if they're using Edge. So, is there any way in which I can make Edge read a locally-held XML file within a local web site?

Comment: Might help: [Microsoft EDGE Enterprise Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793280/microsoft-edge-browser-ignoring-enterprise-mode-list)

Comment: So you have a folder with two files; an index file, and an XML file. The index file is opened locally, using the `file://` protocol, and you're attempting to execute JavaScript that will issue an XHR to read the XML file in the same directory? Is that a fair representation of the issue?

Comment: That's essentially correct, although the files are not in the same folder. The XML files are in a folder which is in the same root folder as the HTML files, but I doubt that makes a difference.