# How can I launch Internet Explorer with a web address from another browser?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, launch, microsoft-edge

Let's say a user browses to www.mysite.com in MS Edge. Rather than continue in Edge I want the page to detect Edge is being used and auto start Internet Explorer with the same URL used in Edge?

Is this possible?

Comment: why are you wanting to launch IE

Comment: As Java doesn't run in Edge I wanted to auto launch IE and run the same page as before.

Comment: Microsoft Edge should be able to identify whether or not the resource being loaded requires Internet Explorer. If you have identified a pattern that should invoke Internet Explorer, but doesn't, please share it. Both Patrick and I work on the Microsoft Edge team, and would be happy to share your scenario with our engineers.

Comment: Hi @Sampson, thanks for getting back to me. The plugin that doens't work in Edge is Java (I work for Visualware and the product MyConnection Server). The applet fails to load in Edge but doesn't auto launch IE....

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer If you don't mind, please shoot me an email (josamp@microsoft.com) with more information. I'd love to take this before the team for further discussion.

Comment: @Sampson just letting you know I did send an email yesterday. Just wanted to make sure you have received it. If not I'll resend

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Received! Thanks again. I'll ping a couple team members and get back to you a.s.a.p.

Comment: Thanks @Sampson, appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If MS Edge does not detect your use of Java and automatically asks the user to use Internet Explorer, the only way to create the expected behaviour is to either

- have your site added to the global compatiblity list managed by Microsoft (for public sites)
- or create an enterprise site list for your company / intranet pages which determines which pages to open in IE instead of Edge.

Once the site is added to one of the lists the users will see a dialogue offering to open the site in Internet Explorer.

You you can find the official documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Charles provided some details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283160/5138360

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not possible. Not in the browser, not through Javascript, etc. Your browser need to have this logic, but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible due to security reasons. If you could do it, also any script on the site would do the same.