# Is it possible to tell Internet Explorer 11 to rather open a site in Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

Our web application currently supports Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer 11 and Edge. (Reason: most recent supported versions of Windows [come with IE11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_version_history#Release_history_for_desktop_Windows_OS_version), except for Windows 7, 8/8.1, and Server 2008R2, but you can install IE11 on them). Since most users are now on Windows 10, which also comes with Edge, it would be nice to only support Edge, or at least to prefer it where possible.

IE11 had a [preview that shipped with the EdgeHTML engine](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2014/11/11/living-on-the-edge-our-next-step-in-helping-the-web-just-work/), but that is no longer available. The developer tools also allow you to "emulate" Edge, but that apparently doesn't change the rendering engine, but just sets the `User-Agent` string.

There's lots of advice on how to make IE 11 compatible with *previous* versions of IE, and [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31283160/120398) to help Edge to push people towards IE11 (including using the [Enterprise Mode Site List to tell Edge to go to IE11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/emie-to-improve-compatibility)), but I want the opposite: if a user opens our application in IE11, I would like to tell the browser to rather open the site in Edge, if Edge is installed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EMSL works both ways, you can mark the preferred browser as edge and it will launch edge. This will only work if you have the ability to push a policy to your user's machines however. There isn't a way to automatically open any browser otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Found a useful [blog entry on this](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/19/edge14-ie11-better-together/)